# Topology defined by a fundamental system of neighbourhoods of zero in a topological group

Tags: general-topology

What are the open sets in a topology specified by a fundamental system of neighbourhoods of $0$ of a topolgical group? Also, how is this topology unique. I searched this online, but the books I found only mention these statements, without specifying what the open sets are and why the topology is unique. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, because to define a topology we need to define a local base at every point in a consistent way. In a topological group $G$, for every $x$ and $y$ we have a homeomorphism of $G$ that maps $x$ to $y$, just use $h(z) = y*x^{-1}*z$. So we can transport a neighbourhood base of $e$ (the identity of $G$) to any other point of $G$, using such $h$. One then checks this is a consistent assignment and so determines the topology on $G$.

Comment: Thanks. My issue is I don't understand what the open sets containing 0 are. Once I know these, I do understand I can get any open by translation and every open set arises this way.

Comment: It all depends on how you define the topological group. Suppose you start with a group $G$ and then you need to define a topology; then it suffices to specify what the open neighbourhoods of $e$ are, or a base for those. Of course, one cannot do this arbitrarily, but there are theorems (in the standard textbooks) that tell you when such an assignment of potential neighbourhoods does give a topological group. I think most groups in practice are specified this way. The topology on the group need not be unique. But once a base is specified, it is uniquely determined. Can you give a concrete ex.?

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familiar with topological groups, but this is what I know from general topology.

You have neighborhood base at every point $x \in G$ (obtained as Henno Brandsma described). Now open sets are obtained uniquely in this manner:

set $U$ is open if and only if for every point $x \in U$ there exists an element $V$ of neighborhood base at $x$ such that $V \subset U$.

Verification of this fact is left as an exercise to the reader :) (and I don't know of a good citation at the moment).

PS: See also the discussion in here: [How can you construct a topology from a fundamental system of neighborhoods?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69518/how-can-you-construct-a-topology-from-a-fundamental-system-of-neighborhoods?rq=1)

Comment: In other words, you are saying that given a system of neighbourhoods of the identity $\mathfrak{V}$, $\{  gV : g \in G, V \in \mathfrak{V}  \}$ is a base for a topology over $G$. However, how can the base's intersection property be proved in this case?